# Problem of compatibility of an external orc and Claudera’s hive

Tags: hive, cloudera-cdh, orc

I can not solve the problem of compatibility of an external orc and Claudera’s hive.

I have cloudera express version 6.3.2 with hive version 2.1.1
In general, it’s strange, I downloaded the latest version of claudera, and there is old hive 2.1.1 there

Case:

- Externally I create some orc (I tried to create it in the local spark and in the same cloudera through map reducer job - the same result)
- I'm trying to read this orc in my claudera even through orcfiledump
- I get
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
  at org.apache.orc.OrcFile $ WriterVersion.from (OrcFile.java:145)
- I downloaded the orc-tools-1.5.5-uber.jar utility locally to my computer
- Also downloaded there the problematic orc
- Performed by java -jar orc-tools-1.5.5-uber.jar meta msout2o12.orc
- Uber jar with its own hadoop inside have read this orc ok
  Structure for msout2o12.orc
  File Version: 0.12 with ORC_135
  Rows: 242
  Compression: ZLIB
  Compression size: 262144

Without any creation of tables, just a hive in the cloudera can stupidly not be able to read the orc using its own utility.
The problem begun from the fact that I created an external table and hiveql on the orc generated such error.
But here it just stupidly reduced the problem to a minimum, just hive --orafiledump can not read the orc.
How to make cloudera read normally orcs? ..
What to tighten up in my cloudera?

Answer (score 0):

It was a big surprize for me.
I returning to parquet.
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Labs/Problem-of-compatibility-of-an-external-orc-and-Claudera-s/m-p/299395/highlight/false#M582